# Visual Studio Recent Project list

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In the start page in VS2008 or any version for that matter is there a way i can get rid of the "Getting Started" and "Visual Studio Headlines" list and have the "Recent Projects" list extend all the way down to the bottom so I can see the last 30 or so projects I have used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change number of Recent Projects displayed on VS2010 Start Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026506/change-number-of-recent-projects-displayed-on-vs2010-start-page)

Answer (score 48):

If you'd like to show more projects in that list, you can increase it in Tools > Options > Environment > General. Change the "items shown in recently used list" to 24 (the maximum).

Other sections will overflow off the page and you'll be able to scroll to see them.

Comment: Understanding that the UI is limiting you to 24, which I assume is based on some decent reasoning, but being a programmer I don't like to feel like I'm limited or forced into using a number that someone tells me to...so do you know if there is a registry or text file setting that can be manually altered to increase PAST the 24 limit? I have lots of vertical space to fill on my monitor now. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Studio, choose Tools->Options.  Right there, you have an option for the number of items in the recently used list.

You can't get rid of the other sections unless you want to go through customizing the start page, but if you set this to 24, you'll see your most recent 24 projects (they don't allow you to view more than 24).

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Options > Environment > General. Change the "items shown in recently used list" to 24 (the maximum).
I prefer to use 12 at most.

Answer (score -1):

Tools->Options->Startup