# Change number of Recent Projects displayed on VS2010 Start Page

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, start-page

Ok, I had VS2010 Start Page set up to display 20+ projects in the Recent Projects section, but while I was messing around with theming and importing/exporting settings I seem to have reset it back to its default of 10, and I can't locate where that setting is.  Does anyone know where the setting for number of recent projects *on the start page*, not the File menu, is located?  I've changed the values in tools\options, environment to be 24 (the maximum) for both items in the recent files section of that page of settings, but alas this does not affect the start page.

TIA

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The setting you're looking for is in `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General (Items shown in recently used lists)`.  Note that when you change the setting to a lower number that you had before, VS will delete the excess items from your list (not just hide them) so when you revert your setting the items won't show up until you explicitly open them again.

Quick test on my local machine confirms that this setting works with VS 2010.

Comment: ugh, that's just wrong, so I have to re-populate the list basically.  VS2008 handles this much better, just limiting what is displayed, not removing the extra.

Comment: +1 - not sure why this was downvoted, but I just tried it and it worked for both my File -> Recent Projects list and my Start Page recent items list, but the list did not show additional projects until *after* I created new projects (so it wasn't just cycling through the 6 most recent), which @Marek indicated.

Answer (score 1):

It's Tools->Options->Environment et cetera. Why do you only write part of the menu tree you have to use. I dont know by head that Environment is reached by Tools Options. :-|

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer

Answer (score 0):

some times it is Not Working in Vs 2010 (SP1) found answer in the link
[Visual Studio 2010, "File > Recent Projects and Solutions" is not a active !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552535/visual-studio-2010-file-recent-projects-and-solutions-is-not-a-active)

Hope it helps some one