# Visual Studio 2010, "File > Recent Projects and Solutions" is not a active !

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ide

I have created hundreds of project on VS 2010 but "File > Recent Projects and Solutions" section is not there ! normally, it should have been like this

[image: It should look like this]

but mine is like below;

[image]

as you can see, also on the start page, there is only two project on the 'Recent Projects' section which is odd given the circumstances.

what should I do here to get it worked?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

here is how customize window looks;

[image]

and here is the regedit view;

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you have two separate problems:

1. The "Recent Files" and "Recent Projects and Solutions" options are missing from your File Menu.
2. You have a lot less Projects in your Recent Projects than you should.

**Solution To #1**: Go to Tools > Customize > Commands.  From there you should be able to select "File | Recent Files" and "File | Recent Projects and Solutions".  Next, you click "Reset All".  Hopefully, you have those two lists back now.

**Solution To #2**: This one is a little bit more complicated because it could be a number of things.

1. First, I would make sure you have the number you want for the "Recent files" options in Tools > Options > Environment > General.
2. If you already had that, check the registry location and make sure you actually have entries here since this is where VS pulls it from.  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ProjectMRUList .
   The 10.0 is for VS 2010.  More info [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/suthish_nair/5769/). If there's nothing there then your recent projects aren't being saved properly.
3. You could try calling `Devenv /ResetSettings` to reset the VS settings. More info at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
4. Finally it could be due to a Windows Explorer setting which hides recent files. This is a possibility because VS takes its directions from the same place with regards to recent files. You would need to make sure HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer "NoRecentDocsHistory" is zero. More info on this possible solution as well as other ideas to this problem can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbide/thread/8886195e-0ac2-4712-8543-4a59a7cee93b).

Comment: the answer was helpful but not solved my problem. firstly, I went to customize page and go to file from  the dropdown. I hit add command and  Recent Projects and Solutions was not there under the file. (***I posted a pic of it on my answer just now**) and I go to regedit and found out that there are only two entry there (***I posted a pic for that two***) last, I entered this ***Devenv.exe /ResetSettings*** on the VS command prompt and it reset the settings but still no File | Recent Projects and Solutions :S

Comment: but there was a 4th option on your post. I am checking it now.

Comment: yeah I remembered now :) I have changed that to 1 couple of months ago :) it totally solved the problem. thanks.

Comment: Great to hear that! I was going to be totally bummed if none of those helped you.

Comment: I have no entries HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ProjectMRUList do you have any idea about why they are not being saved properly? Link you provided doesn't give any clue

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

## open notepad and paste the text below in it without the ===== part.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoRecentDocsHistory"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ProjectMRUList]

===================================================================================
now save it as vs2010-fix.reg or whatever you like just make sure it ends with .reg

Comment: "NoRecentDocsMenu" might also be relevant.