# Where is my "Recent Projects and Solutions" option?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I recently installed Visual Studio 2012, and I've been banging my head against my desk looking for missing options.

I use the Recent Projects and Solutions menu option (under the File menu) a **lot** in Visual Studio 2010, but don't have anything like that in Visual Studio 2012. However, my boss does, so I know there's something wrong with my install or an option I've missed.

I've casually looked through registry settings for anything like "Project" that exists in my 2010 settings but does not exist in my 2012 settings, and came up empty handed. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any "items shown in recently used lists" under Tools->Options?

Comment: I do. It's set to 20, which was the same setting I had in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552535/visual-studio-2010-file-recent-projects-and-solutions-is-not-a-active

Comment: It's not quite the same, I think. It's hard for me to tell exactly what the OP's asking, but I did find the right options in the Customize menu and did get my Recent Projects and Solutions option back.

Comment: Could you try using Ctrl-Q and searching for "Recent Projects and Solutions" to see if that shows you anything?

Comment: Yeah, I'd tried that as well, and it didn't work. This has been solved by following nithins' link to the other question, however. I'm going to post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some part of the upgrade process just removed this menu option for me. Following nithins link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552535/visual-studio-2010-file-recent-projects-and-solutions-is-not-a-active), I followed the instructions the author created to re-create the Recent Projects and Solutions menu item.

For posterity, those steps were (performed in Visual Studio 2012):

1. Under the Tools menu, click **Customize...**
2. Click the **Commands** tab.
3. Change the **Menu bar** selected option in the drop-down list to **File**.
4. Click **Add New Menu**.
5. Click **Modify Selection**, rename to Recent Projects and Solutions.
6. Under the **Menu bar** drop-down list, select **File | Recent Projects and Solutions**.
7. Click **Add Command...**

   (The Add Command menu should appear here.)
8. Under **Categories** on the left-hand side, click **File**.
9. When the Commands list (on the right-hand side) refreshes, click **Recent Project list**, and click OK.
10. Click Close.

Happy project switching!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, but I had the sense that other menu items were missing as well.

What I did was go into Tools => Import & Export Settings, choose Reset all settings, and then select the same profile as when I installed Visual Studio. (General Development Settings.) That fixed the issue.